# Does data stored using Mobile Air AS3 SharedObject persist across app updates?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

Does data stored using Shared Object persist across mobile app updates?
Are there any gotchas that I should know before relying on this? 
Would it be safer to store data using the file system API?

Comment: SharedObjects do persist across updates, unless you mess up with SharedObject internal data structure that will make the data written in old app version lose its integrity. Say you had `HP` field in `so.data` in old version, then you decide to add `maxHP` and then drop `HP` altogether, and those users that have loaded last app update without ever loading intermittent update will have their `maxHP` as `undefined`, forcing bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Shared object is not a reliable type of data storage since it's up to the device owner to allow or limit shared object capacity. Shared object can also be cleared by the owner at any time. You would see tremendous amount of AIR apps done using shared object not because it's a good solution but because app author save a few lines of code using it. More reliable is SQLite as3 built in capability. A simple txt file would do for short amount of data. For more amount of data SQLite is unbeatable and 100% reliable and ultra fast.

Comment: How can a user adjust the storage size for SharedObjects on an AIR app compiled for native iOS? 


1

down vote

favorite


 


Does data stored using Shared Object persist across mobile app updates?

Comment: you ask multiple questions (3) and I answer one of them.